# Оформление фразы "отвечает на вопрос кто что"

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно поставить знаки препинания в следующей фразе?

> Это слово отвечает на вопрос кто что.

Специально не поставил знаков препинания, потому что не могу даже предположить наиболее правильный вариант.

Варианты: *с запятой или без между словами, со знаками вопроса после них или без, в кавычках или без кавычек.*

Даже если этот вопрос не рассматривается правилами, хотелось бы узнать личные предпочтения разных людей. Или, может быть, есть рекомендации по близкому вопросу, из которых можно предположить что-то и на этот случай.

Вопрос вроде бы пустяковый, но всё-таки хотелось бы привыкнуть к какому-то варианту и не сомневаться каждый раз, как написать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможны разные оформления:

- «Это слово отвечает на вопрос**ы** *кто?* **и/,/или** *что?* (или на вопрос *кто?*, или на вопрос *что?*)» — такой вариант, на мой взгляд, лучший, потому что к курсиву, в общем, придраться не за что; однако при письме от руки и в некоторых других ситуациях его трудно или вовсе невозможно применить;
- «Это слово отвечает на вопрос**ы** «кто?» **и/,/или** «что?» (или на вопрос «кто?», или на вопрос «что?»)» — с помощью кавычек можно реализовать необходимое выделение вопросов в предложении, обозначить их самостоятельность.

Можно, конечно, ничего и не добавлять, кроме ***и/,/или***, однако тогда текст будет менее читабельный (иносказательно — тяжелее будет его зрительно воспринять).

P. S. Я не заостряю внимание на смысле высказывания «Это слово отвечает на вопросы «кто?» и «что?»; оно действительно в ходу у учителей начальных классов, а также у учеников и их родителей.

P. P. S. Постановка перед вопросами двоеточия создаст нежелательную и вообще отсутствующую при обычном произнесении паузу. Она не обязательна, потому что здесь вполне приемлемо рассматривать вопросы «кто?» и «что?» как однородные определения.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, Aer!

Comment: Единственное, что меня напрягает в Вашем ответе, это */,/*. Может, поясните?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой это значит «или *и*, или запятая, или союз *или*».

Comment: А-а, ясно, спасибо)

Comment: @Aer _...высказывания «Это слово отвечает на вопросы «кто?» и «что?»_  Мне кажется, что не хватает кавычки в конце.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова я опустил ее (это допустимо), хотя можно выделить предложение „лапками“, вместо «елочек».

Comment: Вот-вот, я то же самое думаю, что у Вас в P. P. S. :)

Answer (score 5):

После слова вопрос, а также перечислением в общем случае, необходимо ставить двоеточие. Перечисляемые заслуживают своего знака вопроса (иначе оно — местоимение, а не союз): ***Это слово отвечает на вопрос: кто? что?*** С некоторой модификацией, что будет «по справедливости»: *Это слово отвечает на вопросы: кто? что?*

Можно отнестись ко второму перечисляемому как ко второстепенному и исключить двоеточие, но при этом сохранить паузу: ***Это слово отвечает на вопрос — кто? (что?)***.

Comment: Спасибо, shampar! Не знаю, мне совсем чужды и двоеточие, и тире перед вопросами. По-моему, двоеточие нужно далеко не перед каждым перечислением.

Comment: Не перед вопросами, а перечислением. Не знал, что некоторые знаки привлекательнее других: «Совсем чужды двоеточие, и тире»... Здесь запятая выглядит непривлекательно.

Comment: Придираетесь, профессор, у Артёма запятая вполне "привлекательна":"... и двоеточие, и тире..."

Comment: Но с Вашим ответом согласна

Comment: @Людмила И с двоеточием согласны, Людмила?

Comment: Да, у меня было "и... и", а у Вас запятые действительно лишние. :)

Comment: Да-с, проглядел первую И.  Виноват. Ну пусть остаётся, как пример  непривлекательного для всех красного словца.

Comment: Когда "как" можно заменить на "в качестве", запятая не нужна. Я про комментарий последний тоже.)

Comment: Артём, двоеточие здесь факультативно, я бы не ставила, но оно возможно. А вот запятая перед как в последнем комментарии возможна как присоединение.